# Python: Appending 2D arrays from meshgrid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array

I'm plotting two surface plots in python obtained from `np.meshgrid`, which I want to append to create only one surface plot. For instance:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# First surface:
x1 = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y1 = np.linspace(0,1,100)
X1,Y1 = np.meshgrid(x1,y1)
Z1 = 2*Y1
solid = ax.plot_surface(X1,Y1,Z1,cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0, antialiased=True)

# Second surface:
x2 = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y2 = np.linspace(1,2,100)
X2,Y2 = np.meshgrid(x2,y2)
Z2 = 2*Y2
solid = ax.plot_surface(X2,Y2,Z2,cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0, antialiased=True)
```

[image]

My first idea was to append them with `np.append`, such that:

```
X = np.append(X1,X2)
Y = np.append(Y1,Y2)
Z = np.append(Z1,Z2)
solid = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0, antialiased=True)
```

But as expected, I got an error since Z was flattened and, moreover, I'm not sure if X and Y are right. In the example above it's trivial how could I create only one surface since both of them have the same angle, but I want to solve for the general case where they could have different inclinations. How can I overcome this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `np.append` is a cover to `np.concatenate`.  As the docs told you, it flattens the inputs when no axis is specified.  `append` is only good for adding one number fo a 1d array. For anything else learn to use `concatenate`.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply fill only one Z array, for example:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = np.linspace(0,2,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.empty_like(Y)
Z[Y < 1] = 2 * Y[Y < 1]
Z[Y >= 1] = 10 * Y[Y >= 1] - 8 # different slope
solid = ax.plot_surface(X , Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=True)
```

Comment: Thank you @Mark, It works, but if I have different shapes of surfaces (instead of planes) that I want to append it may get way more complex instead of just adding together two plots. I'm getting some results by using ``X=np.append(X1,X2,axis=0); Y=np.append(Y1,Y2,axis=0); Z=np.append(Z1,Z2,axis=0); ``, but I'm not pretty sure if it is right.

Comment: Have you tried `np.hstack` and `np.vstack`? They can be used to horizontally stack (side by side) or vertically stack (above each other) 2D arrays.

Comment: I'll take a look. Thanks!